# I have issues with printing out the array in a function

Tags: python

I am trying to make a tictactoe game for my school project. I am using pycharm and somehow inside the print_board function, I get red lines under the board[0]. It seems like it can't get the board elements inside the function. How can I print the board elements inside print_board function?

```py
class tictactoe:

    board = [0, 1, 2,
             3, 4, 5,
             6, 7, 8]

    def print_board(self):
        print(board[0])
```

Comment: is this in a `class`? where is there an error?

Comment: yes this is in a class

Answer (score 1):

`board` is a *class variable*. Put the class name (what I've done) or `self` in front of it to reference it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38156284/2958070) to understand the differences.

```
class tictactoe:

    # this variable is shared between all instances
    # of tictactoe
    board = [0, 1, 2,
         3, 4, 5,
         6, 7, 8]

    def print_board(self):
        print(tictactoe.board[0])


t = tictactoe()
t.print_board()
```

Comment: now i have issues with printing out the print_board() function, Error: print_board() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @stressedoutnut I tested this code and it works... are you calling it with `t.print_board()`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `self.board` in class function:

```
class tictactoe:

    board = [0, 1, 2,
        3, 4, 5,
        6, 7, 8]

    def print_board(self):
        print(self.board[0])
```

The parent scope of function print_board in class tictactoe is where class tictactoe is, not the tictactoe.